Is it possible to find a solution for any $ae^{bx}+cx+d=0$ where $a,b,c\ne0$?
Crosspost from math.codidact.com
So I enjoy solving problems of the form$$ae^{bx}+cx+d=0\\a,b,c\ne0$$however what I don't particularly enjoy is having to solve that equation every single time I come across it. So what I want to know is: Is there a way to solve every non-algebraically solvable equation of that form?
Here is my attempt:$$ae^{bx}+cx+d=0\implies a+(cx+d)e^{-bx}=0\\\implies(cx+d)e^{-bx}=-a\quad\text{rearranging terms}\\\implies\left(\left(-\frac cb\right)\left(-bx-\frac{bd}c\right)\right)e^{-bx}=-a\\\implies\left(-bx-\frac{bd}c\right)e^{-bx}=\frac{ab}c\\\implies\left(-bx-\frac{bd}c\right)e^{-bx-bd/c}=\frac{ab}ce^{-bd/c}$$and now taking the Lambert W of both sides (note that the solution uses $W_k(z)$ since all branches of the product log function will yield a valid solution),$$-bx-\frac{bd}c=W_k\left(\frac{ab}ce^{-bd/c}\right)$$which leads to the solution$$x=-\frac1bW_k\left(\frac{ab}ce^{-bd/c}\right)-\frac dc$$However, my question is: Is my solution valid, or how would one go about finding the solution for any $ae^{bx}+cx+d$ where $a,b,c\ne0$?

Your solution is correct.  It is correct as well in the case $a=0$, with solution $x=-d/c$.

@GEdgar. Your miised the cas where $b=0$

Since $b$ is in the denominator of the formula, my comment omitted the case $b=0$.

$$ae^{bx}+cx+d=0$$
Your solution way is correct (for all $x,d\in\mathbb{C}$ together with $a,b,c\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$).
We see, the equation is a polynomial equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($e^{bx},x$) and with no univariate factor. We therefore don't know how to solve the equation by rearranging for $x$ by applying only finite numbers of elementary operations (means elementary functions) we can read from the equation.
According to the theorem in [Lin 1983], the equation doesn't have solutions except $0$ in the real elementary numbers if the left-hand side of the equation is a polynomial over the algebraic numbers for $e^{bx}$ together with $x$.
We see, the exponential term and the polynomial term of $x$ are connected as a sum. To get the product form that is needed for applying Lambert W, multiplying the equation by $e^{-bx}$ is generally the suitable way in this case.
$\ $
[Lin 1983] Ferng-Ching Lin: Schanuel's Conjecture Implies Ritt's Conjectures. Chin. J. Math. 11 (1983) (1) 41-50

"for all $x,d\in\mathbb C$" What's the point of saying that $x\in\mathbb C$? Isn't that just the variable we're solving for?

@CrSb0001 There are equations solvable with Lambert W where the kind of term simplification depend on whether $x$ is real or complex. But this is not the case with your equation.

Ah, my bad. Although I might have to do some research on that, although the explanation is satisfactory for me otherwise :)

$\left(e^{z_1}\right)^{z_2}=e^{z_1z_2}\ \ (z_2\in\mathbb{Z}\ \text{or}\ -\pi<\text{Im}(z_1)\le\pi)$ (Abramowitz/Stegun 1972 4.2.3); $\ln(e^z)=z\ \ (-\pi<\text{Im}(z)\le\pi)$ (Abramowitz/Stegun 1972 4.2.19)
